# What is the meaning of the word 'Gītā (गीता)'?

Tags: name, terminology, gita, etymology

Well, it's a no-brainer that etymologically, the word 'gītā' literally means 'that which is sung or chanted'.

However, by that logic even Rāmacaritamānasa is sung or chanted, or even a daily ārtī (आरती) at the end of a pujā is also sung or chanted. Infact, the Sāmaveda is also "sung" in its own way.

So, all these texts which are [typically] "sung", may also be called 'Gītā', if one is to follow the literal meaning of the word. But, obviously that's not the case.

#### Questions:

- Are there any "better or clear" definition(s)  of what is meant by the word 'Gītā'?
- What criteria determines a text to be  called as 'Gītā'?

---

Please answer preferably from canonical scriptures.

Otherwise, works of traditional Ācāryas, and/or ancient or modern scholars-researchers may also be given.

Answer (score 0):

Some Gitas like Rama Gita of Adhyama Ramayana , Ashtavakra Gita, Udhava Gita , Ramana Gita, is found to be structured as a philosophic dialogue , whose  purpose is to teach the profound vedantic concepts  . This is just an observation , but not aware of any authentic source which provides definition of  Gita

Comment: Do cite proper sources before answering, especially in my questions, I don't accept unsourced answers. Kindly visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Thanks for the effort though!